# How do you find the path that traverses the largest number of nodes in an undirected graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

Given a an undirected graph and two arbitrary nodes (A and B) in the graph, how do I find the path that passes through the most number of unique nodes in order to navigate between nodes A and B?

I know that you can just depth search it and compare all the lengths, but is there a better way?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) I.e. show us some code.

Comment: How can you do this with depth-first search?

Comment: @Joachim, I haven't tried anything yet. It's more of from an algorithm perspective.

Comment: @default locale: just use depth search to get all of the paths and then the longest one is the answer

Comment: @user1330217, you can't get all of the paths with depth-first search. DFS visits each of the vertex once. To get all of the paths you should visit it two or more times.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg nice article you've posted, BUT! Have you understood the article you've linked to? The article clearly states `it doesn’t mean “show me the code you’ve written, or piss off”`. Also, his wording of the question makes it clear that it's worth helping, since he says `I know that ...`. No matter what he knows, he knows something, he needed assistance to refine his knowledge. Thus, I've +1ed the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's an [NP complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). All you can really do is try every possibility.

Comment: Wikipedia page is about finding a longest path in a graph. OP asks about longest path with fixed ends. It's not obvious that the latter is NP-complete.

Comment: @defaultlocale If the longest-path-with-fixed-ends problem can be solved in polynomial time, the general longest path problem can also be solved in polynomial time (since there are n(n+1)/2 possible pairs of fixed ends).

Comment: @defaultlocale: even with fixed ends you unfortunately have to search every possibility. And to add to what zarkon was saying, longest-path is as difficult as (longest-path-with-fixed-ends * n^2)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This problem makes only sense if we are talking about acyclic graphs, so I assume you you mean that.</strike>

You will have to brute-force-try all possible paths.

To see why, imagine a graph in which you know the longest path of the two node and you add one node. You now have to test every path that contains the new node, including the ones that you already tested, if the node somehow connect to them.

Comment: Why is it necessary that the graph is acyclic?

Comment: If the graph is cyclic the longest path may be indefinite. If the graph is connected, than this will be true for every pair of nodes.

Comment: @steffen OP mentions unique nodes, so I think cyclic graphs are permissible

Comment: @zarkon: true... In that case cyclic graphs are permitted.